# Highlighting Windows or MacOs Screen without impacting clickable area

Tags: windows, macos, api, graphics, screen

I want to know if there is a way to highlight specific points on the windows or Mac screen without impacting on application that is running and its clickable area.
To better understand the question, imagine some area of the LCD of laptop is malfunctioning, e.g. pressed and highlighted with purple color. We can still see what is going on underneath the purple area and it is clickable and regardless what is the color of item on that point, it shows purple.

Is it possible to do it by software and programmatically ? Is there any API or something to manipulate output of graphic card for specific point, draw something or highlight without impaction on the application running under it.

I know that I could write it better way, but excuse me since English is not my first language...

Comment: I don't understand this question.  There's lots of ways to draw things on the screen, but I don't understand what this has to do with "purple color", which sounds like you want to change the color of a dead pixel.   **What are you really trying to do?**

Comment: What I am trying to say is having screen highlighted but when using screen recorder software it doesn’t detect that.

Comment: @selbie thanks for respond, I meant how to have screen highlighted like a broken screen e.g. purple colour but when you use screen recorder software it doesn’t recognize it and record properly. Only person sitting in front of screen see the highlights. In fact if you take screenshot or record screen with any then you won’t see any highlight.